# Defining an interface in Python

Tags: python

I'm wondering whether we can use the `typing` package to produce the definition of an "interface", that is, a class/object in Python 3.

It seems that the usual way to define an "interface" in Python is to use an *abstract class*defined using ABC, and use that as your type parameter. However, since Python is dynamically typed, a fully abstract type is an interface that is nothing more than a typing hint for python. In runtime, I would expect to have zero impact from said interface. A base class can have methods that are inherited, and that's not what I want.

I'm based a lot of this on my experience with TypeScript - it enables us to very easily define object types through `interface` or the `type` keyword, but those are only used by the type checker.

Let me make my use case clearer with an example:

Let's say I'm defining a function `foo` as below:

```
def foo(bar):
    nums = [i for i in range(10)]
    result = bar.oogle(nums)
    return result
```

`foo` is, therefore, a method that expects to receive an instance of an object that must have a method `oogle` that accepts a list of integers. I want to make it clear to callers that this is what `foo` expects from `bar`, but `bar` can be of any type.

Comment: In your intended use-case, how do you envision defining what objects do and don't count as instances of your interface? Would you define the interface as a list of classes that implement it? Or would each class that implements it have some sort of marker? Or something else? I've never used TypeScript, so I'm not sure what sort of use pattern you have in mind, and how exactly you intend for it to function differently from an ABC that defines no methods.

Comment: Hey @CrazyChucky, thanks for the fast reply! My main goal is to somehow inform implementers what I expect an object that is a parameter of a method I'm writing to look like. I'll add an example above.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol might help.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist That seems like it's probably the answer, if you'd like to post it as such. What a neat thing to know about!

Comment: glad that helps! i'm fine leaving it as a comment. feel free to self-answer if you feel it might help others. happy pythoning!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you for the comment, it's really what I am after.

Answer (score 7):

[PEP544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) introduced `Protocol` classes, which can be used to define interfaces.

```
from typing import Any, List, Protocol

class Bar(Protocol):
    def oogle(self, quz: List[int]) -> Any:
       ...

def foo(bar: Bar):
    nums = [i for i in range(10)]
    result = bar.oogle(nums)
    return result
```

If you execute your script using Python you will not see any difference though. You need to run your scripts with [Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), which is a static type checker that supports protocol classes.